# Assume the determinant is 0 of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question:

If a matrix is given to be invertible (it for example has infinitely many solutions), are you allowed to assume that the determinant of the matrix is not equal to 0?

I am not sure, but I think I once heard that you are never allowed to assume that the determinant of a matrix is 0, you always have to prove it through calculations, but I might be wrong..

Would greatly appreciate an answer :)

Comment: A matrix is invertible _precisely_ when it's determinant is non-zero.

Comment: If a square matrix $A$ is invertible, it's determinant is non zero because $1 = \det(I) = \det(AA^{-1}) = \det(A)\det(A^{-1})$...

Comment: The answer depends on the underlying *structure*, i.e. it depends on where the matrix entries are taken from. The basic fact is that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A)$ is invertible. Over a field, $\det(A)$ is invertible iff $\det(A)\ne0$. Over a commutative ring, however, while $\det(A)$ is invertible implies that $\det(A)\ne0$, the converse is false.

Comment: Note that $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions implies that $A$ is not invertible. See the invertible matrix theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

Answer (score 2):

### Determinants

A matrix is invertible if it has an inverse, right? That is, a matrix $A$ is invertible if there exists a matrix $A^{-1}$ such that
$$
A\cdot A^{-1} = I_{n} = A^{-1}\cdot A.
$$
Now, suppose the determinant of matrix $A$ is $\det(A) = a$. Then if $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $A$, we have that $\det(A^{-1}) = a^{-1}$. This is because the determinant is *multiplicative*, so
$$
\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)
$$
and the determinant of $I_{n}$ is $1$. To rephrase this, if $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $A$ then
$$
\det(A)\det(A^{-1}) = 1.
$$
Now given this, if a matrix $A$ has determinant $0$, is there a matrix $A^{-1}$ such that
$$
\det(A)\det(A^{-1}) = 1?
$$
Clearly not since $0$ times anything is always $0$, so there is no $A^{-1}$ that satisfies the above.

### Linear Maps

Another perspective is to think matrices as *linear maps*. If you've not seen matrices expressed this way, observe the following example. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be defined by
$$
f(x, y) = (x, y, x + y).
$$
We can see this as $f$ sending the vector $(x, y)$ to the vector $(x, y, x + y)$. In matrix form we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ x + y \\\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The matrix multiplying $(x, y)$ is the matrix that corresponds to the linear map $f$. In the case of a square $n \times n$ matrix, this corresponds to a map from $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

If the matrix corresponding to a linear map has determinant $0$, this is because the linear map itself is not invertible. Try to see this for yourself with some examples. Note that if $A$ is the matrix corresponding to a linear map $f$, then $A^{-1}$ is the matrix corresponding to the linear map $f^{-1}$.

---

Following amd's comment, this answer assumes that you're working with matrices whose entries are in $\mathbb{R}$.